# Probability of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Was looking at previous exam questions and came across this:

A manufacturer of lie detectors is testing its newest design. It asks 300 people to lie deliberately and another 500 people to tell the truth. Of those who lied, the lie detector caught 200. Of those who told the truth, the lie detector accused 200 of lying. Let L describe the event that a person is a liar and N the event that the lie detector accuses a person of lying.

How do you calculate the following properties?

(1) P(L ∩ N)

(2) P(L′ ∩ N)

(3) P(L′ ∪ N′)

(4) P(L|N)

(5) P(L′|N′)

Comment: I don't know which part of this you find difficult.  If you could present your current thoughts then people will be able to give you some effective assistance.

Answer (score 1):

For a start you are given: $P(L)=\frac{3\color{gainsboro}{00}}{8\color{gainsboro}{00}},\; P(L')=\frac{5\color{gainsboro}{00}}{8\color{gainsboro}{00}},\; P(N\mid L) = \frac{2\color{gainsboro}{00}}{3\color{gainsboro}{00}},\; P(N\mid L') = \frac{2\color{gainsboro}{00}}{5\color{gainsboro}{00}}$

For everything else, use $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)\cdot P(Y\mid X)$, or $P(X\cup Y) = 1 - P(X'\cap Y')$.

Eg: $P(L\cap N) = P(L)\cdot P(N \mid L)$